# Sorting a JSON Array based on key

Tags: javascript

Good day, I am trying to sort a JSON array based on the dictionary Value.
Before serialization, the dictionary is displayed in alphabetical order which is correct, but once serialized, the array is sorted based on the dictionary Key.
An example is:

```
{[692:"!Entry1"]}, {[5:"!Entry2"]}, {[75:"!Entry3"]}
```

is sorted as

```
{[5:"!Entry2"]}, {[75:"!Entry3"]}, {[692:"!Entry1"]}
```

Any help please

Comment: That's not valid json.

Comment: use http://www.jsonlint.org to check for valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid JSON, and if it were, it wouldn't be an array, it would be an object. Objects are not sorted.

If it were an array, it would be sparse. JSON doesn't have a way to represent sparse arrays.

In JavaScript (no jQuery required), you can express that sparse array like this:

```
var a = [];
a[692] = "!Entry1";
a[5]   = "!Entry2";
a[75]  = "!Entry3";
```

But as you noted, it will be sorted by key, not value (e.g., `"!Entry2"`, `"!Entry3"`, `"!Entry1"`).

Neither JSON nor JavaScript has a way to sort basic types (arrays or objets) by the *value* of the entries.

In JSON (or JavaScript), you could do this:

```
[{"692":"!Entry1"}, {"5":"!Entry2"}, {"75":"!Entry3"}]
```

...which represents an array of objects, where each object has a property with a name like `"75"` which has a value giving your "entry" strings. But it would be **very** hard to work with.

Another way would be:

```
[
    {key: "692", value: "!Entry1"},
    {key: "5",   value: "!Entry2"},
    {key: "75",  value: "!Entry3"}
]
```

Which is an array of objects, where each object has a `key` property giving the key, and a `value` property giving the value.

Comment: "no jQuery required": blasphemy!

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester: :-)

Comment: Until one day a browser decides that an array has fixed length :p

Comment: apologies for the buggy code, it was only meant to be a representation of the list of items that I work with

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I came across it while looking for a similar solution. I ended up making a function that performs an insertion sort across an array of JSON objects based on a key, so I thought I'd share for anyone else who may need this functionality. Here's the code, it works from greatest to least or least to greatest depending on the parameter 'isGreatestToLeast' (boolean):

```
/**
 * Performs an insertion sort on an array of json object based on a specified key
 * @param jsonArray - an array of json objects
 * @param key - the name of the key that should be used to determine the value
 * @param isGreatestToLeast - boolean, is the sort least to greatest or greatest to least?
 * @returns {array} of objects
 */
function insSortJsonArr(jsonArray, key, isGreatestToLeast){

    for(var i = 1; i < jsonArray.length; i++){

        var next = jsonArray[i];
        var j = i;

        if(isGreatestToLeast){

            while(j > 0 &&  next[key] >  jsonArray[j - 1][key]){

                jsonArray[j] = jsonArray[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
        } else{

            while(j > 0 &&  jsonArray[j - 1][key] < next[key]){

                jsonArray[j] = jsonArray[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
        }

       jsonArray[j] = next;
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

Anybody is welcome to use it. Let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: the else condition should be `jsonArray[j - 1][key] > next[key]`

Answer (score 0):

The exact order of keys inside an object can't be relied upon.

If you want to preserve the order, your structure should be something like this:

```
[{692:"!Entry1"}, {5:"!Entry2"}, {75:"!Entry3"}]
```

Comment: Which is also not valid JSON (it's valid JavaScript, though), and would be *very* hard to work with (as I point out in my answer).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yep, I deliberately used the term "structure" instead of valid JSON notation :)